# Is there a scriptable way to extract asm from a function? (VS2010, gcc)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, gcc, automation, disassembly

I would like to be able to compare the asm generated by visual studio and gcc for a particular function.  For the sake of argument, lets say that we already know this function exists in both binaries.

What i would like to do is simply run a script that will extract the desired function disassembled (asm) from both binaries.  I know how to examine the asm in Visual Studio and gdb respectivly, but i'm a little stumped how to do this in any kind of scriptable manner.

Any ideas or theories would help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both compilers support a command line option which causes it to leave the generated assembly language as the result of compilation, instead of an object file.  With `MSVC`, use `/Fa[file]` (and generates the `.obj` too—tested with VS2008).  With `gcc`, the `-S` command line option leaves assembly output.

While using the option can be done in the Visual Studio IDE, it seems like a scripted comparison would use a batch file, or other script command line interpreter to compile the files, extract the proper portion with `sed` or whatever, and then do whatever comparison is needed.

```
gcc -S x.c       (generates x.S)
cl  /Fa  x.c     (generates x.asm and x.obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most compilers can generate assembly output. The syntax differs, though. gcc has the source operand first on all asm instructions, while most other compilers and assemblers have the destination operand first. You can disassemble the object file instead if you want to get the same syntax for all compilers, but you loose some information about variable names etc.
I can recommend the [objconv](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#objconv) disassembler.